# CORS Problem after preflight in asp.net webapi

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I was having a cors problem with requests requiring preflight (only these requests were rejected by cors). After reading a bit I discovered that the iis responded to the preflight before it reached my application, so it did not use the explicit policies in WebApiConfig.cs
But i found a way around this.

```
 <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
       <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
       <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
       <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
   </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

This make the iis let the OPTION request reach the app. Perfect, now the response is correct, with my cors policy headers correctly set. but the GET request that comes after the options preflight doesn't have the headers set.
The funny thing is that if I modify the request so that it does not use token therefore it does not require preflight (no authorization header present) it behaves correctly(no cors error).

forcing the headers in the web.config is not an option I have to be able to set them dynamically in the application

preflight request
[image: preflight request]

Get Request
[image]

Cors error
[image]

WebApiConfig.cs configuration

```
var cors = new System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*") { SupportsCredentials = true };
configuration.EnableCors(cors);
```

Comment: Can you add the error that you're getting for the GET request that comes after the options preflight?

Comment: @kylejrp yeah, I did not include them because I did not think they would be helpful